# No logro insertar todos los datos de un archivo csv

Tags: php, mysql

Uso mysql, slim framework y php, deseo insertar varias filas de mi csv, ya lo recorri, veo que se me imprime todos los valores cuando hago echo pero al momento de realizar el insert solo logro hacer un solo insert a la tabla cuando se deberian hacer varios insertando todos los valores de mi archivo. Adjunto mi codigo.

```
public function prueba($pathFile){
$ruta = dirname(__FILE__) . '/files_cventas/'. $pathFile;
$archivo = fopen($ruta, "r");
$numeroDeFila=0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($archivo, ",")) !== FALSE) {

if ($numeroDeFila > 0) {
    echo "DATOS DEL USUARIO: ". $numeroDeFila;
    echo "anio: ". $data[0];
    echo "mes: ". $data[1];
    echo "codigo_vendedor: ". $data[2];
    echo "nombre_vendedor: ". $data[3];
    echo "ventas_presupuestadas: ". $data[4];
    echo "\n\n";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cumplimiento_ventas(anio, mes, codigo_vendedor,
     nombre_vendedor, ventas_presupuestadas) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
          $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3], $data[4]);
          $result = $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->close();
            if($result){
                return RECORD_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
            }else{
                return RECORD_CREATION_FAILED;
            }
    }

      $numeroDeFila++;

       }
    }
```

Comment: Tienes dos `return` que finalizan el ciclo, por eso solo se inserta el primer resultado. Debes buscar otra forma para analizar cuántos registros se insertaron y cuántos fallaron.

Comment: Si era eso, puse un echo cuando el result era positivo para no hacer el return, muchas gracias :D